# Angular 4 select box two way data binding

Tags: html, angular

```
<select [(ngModel)]="scheduleComment" class="form-control" 
            (change)="getSchedCommentsList($event)"
            #sched="ngModel">
                <option [ngValue]="null">Choose Schedule     Comments</option>     
                <option *ngFor="let scheduleComment of scheduleComments" 
                                      [ngValue]="scheduleComment">{{scheduleComment}}</option>
</select>
```

I've tried using the [(ngModel)] capability to update a field with a new value assigned within a component (separate from the assignment made within the select '*ngFor="let scheduleComment of scheduleComments'" option).

However, the select box value seems impervious to any updates outside the of the initial selection.  I've seen other examples using ngChangeForm as well but that doesn't seem to be applicable to this situation, unfortunately.

Can anyone provide an example of how this might be done?  That is updating a value independently from the initial value selected.

Thanks

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4avseo i've made this demo and i don't really know what is your problem

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response.   Using the demo example the value to the right of "select is:"  could be used to update the value in the "change from code" selection box for instance,  So obviously the field to the right would be input capable , but the point I'm trying to make is that the choose schedule comments can be modified from somewhere other than the selection box..

Comment: I'm really sorry english is not my native language so I have some problems understanding your problem. If you want to modify label `Choose Schedule Comments` from code. You got to make this a variable and change that variable value.
If you want to change selectable options like adding a new one, removing, changing value. You got to make changes to the scheduleComments array, just like you do with  an ordinary array - Angular will refresh selection options automatically. (I've changed demo a bit but i doubt it will help you).

Comment: You are getting me very close to what I need and your examples have been very helpful.  However, "change from code" suggests that it will update what's selected in the drop down, but it doesn't do that, unfortunately.  "change label" has the correct option, since the default label text has been changed.  I'm just looking for the same behavior for the change() procedure.

Comment: Well I updated example again to update value. It will change selected value to `"1"`. Making up my mind. If you need to change selected value you need to change the variable value you are binding to in this case `scheduleComment`. If it has the value `"1"` then it will select option that has value `"1"`.

Comment: I agree that more complex logic will be need to accomplish this operation.  Thank you again for your time and effort.  ~Sean